# Is this product of $L^2$ functions also an $L^2$ function?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $I=(l_0,l_1)$ and $g(x)= f(x)\chi_{(\alpha,\beta)}$ where $(\alpha,\beta)\subset I$ and $f \in L^\infty(I)$ with $f(x)\geq c>0$ for all $x\in I$.

Now, if $h \in L^2(I)$, is the product $g(x)h(x) \in L^2(I)$ if $f(x)$ is also bounded?

**My attemps:**

Since $g(x)$ is measurable in $I$, then $g(x)h(x)$ is measurable. Now, I need to show that ${|gh|}^2 \in L^1(I)$. let $K\geq f(x)$, then

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\int_{I} (g(x)h(x))^2\,dx&=\int_{I} (f(x)\chi_{(\alpha,\beta)}\,h(x))^2\,dx\\
&\leq K^2\int_{I} h(x)^2\,dx
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

This proves that $g(x)h(x) \in L^2(I)$. Am I right? What about only requiring $f(x) \in L^\infty(I)$?

I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Yes, that's right. Being in $L^\infty$ means being bounded apart from a set of zero measure, so the same applies.

Comment: @Berci So ,the product of an $L^\infty(I)$ funcion with an $L^p(I)$ function is always $L^p(I)$?

Comment: If the measure of the ambient space is finite, then yes.